# Wordpress ajax insert and delete if already inserted delete the post id stored in custom table

Tags: themes, ajax

I am creating a wordpress ajax system to insert a post id. If the same post id was selected by logged in user then it wants to delete the particular id.
**For that i am creating a table like below it works.**

```
function compare_new_table(){
            global $wpdb;
            global $compare_db_version;
            $compare_table = $wpdb->prefix . 'compare_post';
            $sql = "CREATE TABLE $compare_table (
                `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
                `post_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
                `post_type` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
                PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
                KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
                KEY `post_id` (`post_id`)
                )";

             require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
             dbDelta( $sql );
            add_option( 'compare_db_version', $compare_db_version );
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'compare_new_table');
```

**For enqueing script i am using lile below.**

```
// Loads frontend scripts and styles
function sha_compare_enque_script()
{
wp_enqueue_script( 'com-compare-scripts', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/inc/compare/js/compare.js', array( 'jquery' ), '0.6', false );
wp_localize_script( 'com-compare-scripts', 'com', array(
'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
'nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'com_nonce' ),
'errorMessage' => __( 'Something went wrong', 'com' )
) );   
}      
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sha_compare_enque_script' );
```

**After that started ajax and php code**

```
    add_shortcode( 'compare-post-btn', array($this, 'compare_button_shortcode') );           
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_com_action', array($this, 'compare_post_shortcode') );


    function link_button_compare( $post_id ) {

    if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return;
    }

    $status = $this->get_post_status( $post_id, get_current_user_id() );
    ?>

    <a class="wpf-compare-link" href="#" data-id="<?php echo $post_id; ?>">
        <?php if ( $status ) { ?>
        <div class="wpf-compare"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i><span class="compare-text"><?php _e( 'uncompare', 'com' ); ?><span></div>
        <?php } else { ?>
                    <div class="wpf-not-compare"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i> <span class="fav-text"><?php _e( 'compare', 'com' ); ?></span></div>
        <?php } ?>
    </a>

    <?php
}


    function compare_post() {
    check_ajax_referer( 'com_nonce', 'nonce' );

    // bail out if not logged in
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
        wp_send_json_error();
    }

    // so, the user is logged in huh? proceed on
    $post_id = isset( $_POST['post_id'] ) ? intval( $_POST['post_id'] ) : 0;
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    if ( !$this->get_post_status( $post_id, $user_id ) ) {

        $this->insert_compare( $post_id, $user_id );

        wp_send_json_success( '<div class="com-compsre"><span class="compare-text">Uncompare<span></div>');
    } else {

        $this->delete_compare( $post_id, $user_id );

        wp_send_json_success( '<div class="com-not-compare"><span class="compare-text">Compare</span></div>');
    }
}


function get_post_status( $post_id, $user_id ) {
    $sql = "SELECT post_id FROM {$this->table} WHERE post_id = %d AND user_id = %d";

    return $this->db->get_row( $this->db->prepare( $sql, $post_id, $user_id ) );
}


public function insert_compare( $post_id, $user_id ) {
    $post_type = get_post_field( 'post_type', $post_id );

    return $this->db->insert(
        $this->table,
        array(
            'post_id' => $post_id,
            'post_type' => $post_type,
            'user_id' => $user_id,
        ),
        array(
            '%d',
            '%s',
            '%d'
        )
    );
}

public function delete_compare( $post_id, $user_id ) {
    $query = "DELETE FROM {$this->table} WHERE post_id = %d AND user_id = %d";

    return $this->db->query( $this->db->prepare( $query, $post_id, $user_id ) );
}


function get_compare( $post_type = 'all', $user_id = 0, $count = 10, $offset = 0 ) {
    $where = 'WHERE user_id = ';
    $where .= $user_id ? $user_id : get_current_user_id();
    $where .= $post_type == 'all' ? '' : " AND post_type = '$post_type'";


    $sql = "SELECT post_id, post_type
            FROM {$this->table}
            $where
            GROUP BY post_id
            ORDER BY post_type
            LIMIT $offset, $count";

    $result = $this->db->get_results( $sql );

    return $result;
}

function link_button_compare( $post_id ) {

    if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return;
    }

    $status = $this->get_post_status( $post_id, get_current_user_id() );
    ?>

    <a class="wpf-compare-link" href="#" data-id="<?php echo $post_id; ?>">
        <?php if ( $status ) { ?>
        <div class="wpf-compare"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i><span class="compare-text"><?php _e( 'uncompare', 'com' ); ?><span></div>
        <?php } else { ?>
                    <div class="wpf-not-compare"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i> <span class="fav-text"><?php _e( 'compare', 'com' ); ?></span></div>
        <?php } ?>
    </a>

    <?php
}
```

**js file for this ajax**

```
jQuery(function($) {

    $('a.com-compare-link').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var $self = $(this);

        var data = {
            post_id: $self.data('id'),
            nonce: com.nonce,
            action: 'com_action'
        };

        $self.addClass('com-compare-loading');

        $.post(com.ajaxurl, data, function(res) {

            if (res.success) {
                $self.html(res.data);

            } else {
                alert(com.errorMessage);
            }

            // remove loader
            $self.removeClass('com-compare-loading');
        });
    });


    $('a.com-not-compare').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var $self = $(this);

        var data = {
            post_id: $self.data('id'),
            nonce: com.nonce,
            action: 'com_action'
        };

        $self.addClass('com-compare-loading');

        $.post(com.ajaxurl, data, function(res) {

            if (res.success) {
                window.location.reload();

            } else {
                alert(com.errorMessage);
            }

            // remove loader
            $self.removeClass('com-compare-loading');
        });
    });

$('a.com-compare-link').click(function(){
  $('#comparebutton').show();
}); 

});
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @milo My question is to insert post id and also logged in user id. if the same user id and post id are added it needs to remove that particular row from custom table in mysql.

Comment: That's not a question, that's a description of what you want it to do. What parts of it work, what parts don't? What sort of debugging have you done already? If you're expecting anyone to help you, you need to provide a lot more than just a wall of code.

Comment: @Milo Creating table works fine the inserting values works fine also deleting works fine but the comparing if already preset not woking.

Comment: I don't see any query involving the "new table" you've created (?) , it's not clear what and where are you searching this record

Comment: @AndreaSomovigo Please see this function function compare_new_table()